# "Work" tab in "Lubuntu Netbook" session is messed up

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, ubuntu-netbook

I have just upgraded my laptop (Samsung NP300E5A, with 15.6" 1366x768 LCD) from Lubuntu 12.04 to Lubuntu 12.10 (full reinstall).

I used to use **"Lubuntu Netbook" session** (one of choices that login manager offers).  It shows installed programs not only in "start menu", but also full screen in tabs: "Internet", "Work", "Learn", "Play", "Preferences".  Some of those tabs are divided further, like e.g. "Work" tab which includes among others "Work > Accessories" and "Work > Office" subcategories (sub-tabs).

After installing a few programs Lubuntu Netbook now has totally messed up "Work" tab, and only this tab, see screenshot below (half size).

[image: Lubuntu Netbook session screenshot - messed up full-screen submenu]

For example:

- AbiWord is both in "Work" (as 'AbiWord Word Processor') and "Work > Office" (as 'AbiWord'), and they use different icons
- Same with Catfish File Search; it is as 'catfish' with default [*] icon in "Work", and as 'Catfish File Search' in "Work > Accessories" with magnifying glass icon.
- Dvdisaster is shown in "Work" tab twice, once with larger icon and 'Additional error protection for CD/DVD media' as on mouseover description, and once with smaller icon and 'data loss/scratch/aging protection for CD/DVD media' as description / hint.
- There is "GDebi Package Installer" in "Work" tab instead of in "Preferences" like "Synaptic" is.
- There is 'bash', 'bc', 'dash' etc. cluttering "Work" tab, all with default [*] icon.

There are no such problems with other tabs.

What could be the source of this mess, and how to fix it?  How to remove duplicates and console/commandline applications like 'bash' from there?

Answer (score 1):

I've just installed Lubuntu on two machines, didn't have the issue.  Maybe it was a bad install?

Since this is a fresh install, I would recommend, reformatting and trying again

Comment: I think it was something I installed, because I seem to remember that "Work" tab was not broken just after install. But anyway installing package should not break `lxlauncher`.